# I want to achieve this type of pagination in React Native using Flatlist to render the data. Is there any component to achieve this pagination?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

[image: Pagination]

```
    <FlatList
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    numColumns={2}
    style={{width: '100%', paddingBottom: 200}}
    // contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}
    data={currentVideos}
    renderItem={renderVideoCard}
    keyExtractor={video => video.id.toString()}
    onEndReached={() => {
    if (currentPage < totalPages) {
    goToPage(currentPage + 1);
    }
    }}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
    columnWrapperStyle={{
    flexShrink: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    }}/>
```

This is the code that I am using rn to render the data. I want to add Pagination number at the bottom and the data changes each time the page number changes.